# How to schedule an irregular backup script requiring user confirmation

Tags: boot, gnome-terminal, cron, schedule, anacron

I have a backup script which requires user interaction. I would like to schedule it to run, say, once a week.

The constraints are that (1) the computer boots straight into Gnome and is turned off daily, (2) the user must be able to opt out of running the script and see any script output on the screen.

I understand that Gnome Scheduler uses `anacron` for weekly cron jobs, and that missed jobs are run on startup. But that's no use if the job requires a terminal window for user confirmation, because the script will run before Gnome starts.

Gnome, of course, has Startup Applications, for programs to be run on startup. But that's only so helpful, since I don't want my script running at every startup.

A solution?

Comment: Can you be sure you'll be available for providing input when the script runs? If you can modify the script, have it read from a config file. Or change the cronjob to launch a terminal to run the script.

Comment: Your script is at odds with running it automatically. Ideally, if you are running the script automatically no user input should be required. I think it is best to re-write your script. If that is impossible I suggest use use expect. See http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts

Comment: @muru Yes, of course I'll be available, it's at boot time and I just pressed the On switch. I know I need to launch a terminal, but how can that fit into the boot process? As I mention in the question, I boot straight into Gnome, and I don't see how it is possible in that case to launch a terminal from `rc.local`. The obvious solution, as I also mentioned, is to put a terminal script into Gnome's "Startup applications", but I don't how to make that conditional so that it runs once a week and not at every single boot.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks but I don't see how this is "too broad". It is a situation that many people have surely faced, hence my question here. I would like to run a script requiring yes-no user confirmation, at boot, one time per week. That is all. Perhaps I make it sound too complicated. Perhaps the word "script" is wrong. If so, could you help me rewrite the question?

Comment: @Sqerstet the script itself could have check for the day of the week or of last run, or be wrapped in such a check.

Comment: Take a look at expect, I already gave you a link. Running a script, at boot, twice a week, starts to become more complex, thus your question is "too broad". If you need assistance, post your script, error reports, crontab, logs, etc. You may also be referred to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @muru Yes, that was what I was thinking too. Create a log file for the time of last run, launch terminal if more than 7 days, and put script in "Startup applications". I guess I will try that and add the answer here if successful. Thank you.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I did look at `expect`. It just seemed a little complicated for what is really a very simple problem, however badly I've described it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Question rewritten to be more precise. And I have a solution based on @muru's idea. Could you reopen?

Comment: @Sqerstet I have reopened the question, I don't really see how this is "too-broad" anyway. Please, post your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based partly on feedback in the comments, here is the solution I came up with.

**1. Create an empty logfile**, `~/.lastbackup.log`, to contain a record of the time the backup script last ran.

**2. Create a wrapping scheduler script**, `~/scheduler.sh`, to be placed in Gnome's Startup Applications (`~/.config/autostart`), to check the logfile date at each boot and decide whether to run the main script:

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUPINTERVAL=3 # in days
DATETODAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
DATELASTBACKUP=$(</path/to/.lastbackup.log) # get last backup date from logfile
DATEDIFF=$(( ($(date --date=$DATETODAY +%s) - $(date --date=$DATELASTBACKUP +%s) )/(60*60*24) ))
if [ "$DATEDIFF" -ge "$BACKUPINTERVAL" ] ; then
    # more than 3 days since last backup, so run script
    /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -e /path/to/backup.sh
fi
```

**3. Create the main backup script**, `~/backup.sh`, to run when necessary:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/dialog --yesno "Do backup now?" 8 40 # user can opt out
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    # do backup
    # user can check output to screen
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        # write date to logfile
        echo $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") > /path/to/.lastbackup.log
        echo 'Backup done'
        read
    fi
fi
```